# URL re-writing using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a URL:
**domain.com/abc/hotel_detail.php?id=2**

And I want to do a URL re-write to make it look like this :
**domain.com/abc/hotel_detail/2**

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=20$                   
RewriteRule   ^abc/hotel_detail/([0-9]+)$  ^abc/hotel_detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The first part contains code for removing the extension(.php) from pages.

When I try to open this link **domain.com/abc/hotel_detail/2** , it gives me object not found error.

Can Someone please tell me whats wrong with the code?

Comment: I have made certain changes in the .htaccess file
and now it looks like :
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^hotel_detail/([0-9]+)/?$    ^hotel_detail.php?product_name=$1    [NC,L]

still no luck

Comment: `^hotel_detail.php?product_name=$1 [NC,L]` - just remove `^` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=20$
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^abc/hotel_detail/([0-9]+)$  ^abc/hotel_detail.php?id=$1 [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,R]
```

should work. I removed `RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=20`

Your first rewritecond and rule was overwriting the second one, switching them around should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
 RewriteRule        ^abc/hotel_detail/([0-9]*)$ abc/hotel_detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

([0-9]*) miltiply sign. 
and the ^ for the real link